# Nodejs + Axios Post returns undefined value

Tags: node.js, api, axios

I am using React + NodeJS & Axios but have been trying to send a post request but experiencing difficulties.

The request seems to be posting successfully, but all actions at the nodejs server is returning in the "undefined" data value, even if the data is passed successfully shown in the console.

REACT

```
const fireAction = (data1, data2) => {
    const data = JSON.stringify({data1, data2})
    const url = `http://localhost:5000/data/corr/fire`;
    const config = {
        headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
           'Authorization': 'AUTHCODE',
        }
    }
        axios.post(url, data, config)
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
}

fireAction("Oklahoma", "Small apartment")
```

NODE

```
app.post('/data/corr/fire', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const data = req.body.data1;
      console.log(data)
    } catch(e) {
      res.send({success: "none", error: e.message})
    }
  });
```

Result of node: "undefined"

I have added the following body parser:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

I am not sure why this error is happening. I see there is similar questions to mine: however none of them are applicable as I'm using both express and body parser which is already suggested.

Comment: You're setting the header as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but then encode in JSON. You need to pick one of these and use the appropriate header and serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're POSTing JSON with a content-type meant for forms. There's no need to manually set `content-type` if you're sending JSON, but if you want to manually override it, you can use `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`, and access the response in your route with `req.body`. If it does need to be formencoded, you'll need to build the form:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('data1', data1);
params.append('data2', data2);
axios.post(url, params, config);
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Really appreciate your help. Tried to overwrite the content type with application/json, however I'm now getting the "data is not defined" error when trying to console out the req.body. I'm clueless what I have missed..

Comment: Did you change or remove that variable initialization in your route? `const data = req.body; console.log(data)`, or maybe `const { data1, data2 } = req.body`?

Comment: Getting this error back: Cannot destructure property 'data1' of 'req.body' as it is undefined. Just checked the headers and they now pass the value of "application/json" as well. Using const { data1, data2 } = req.body

Comment: Ooh, seems like I called the bodyParser too late in the code. Moved it now and works like a charm! Thank you very much for your help. Much appreciated! Happy new year & take care!

Comment: You're welcome, and happy new year! Oh, and there's no need for both the Express and bodyParser middlewares; you can use `app.use(express.json()); app.use(express.urlencoded())` (`extended` is the default) and remove `bodyParser` entirely.